# Can .net core detect OS on WSL execution?

Tags: .net-core, cross-platform, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The following code I found here on SO to detect the Windows at runtime, but it thinks WSL Ubuntu is Windows. Any better way? Or?

```
public static bool IsWindows
{
    get
    {
        var osver = Environment.OSVersion;
        return osver.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOH! I was running the EXE built by Visual Studio and WSL detects that and just runs it as if it was in a Windows Console. Build on Ubuntu and it creates a linux executable.

Comment: FYI you can build cross platform with command line arguments. Also can build to package as a single EXE which is nice especially for docker.

Comment: For WSL and Windows the platform is Win32NT, but if I want to write a code that runs only on WSL and Ubuntu it does not work, because for Ubuntu the platform is Unix.

Comment: @Catalin yes build it for Ubuntu and that's where that can run.