# C#: .NET 7.0 console helloworld crash on Linux? (built but fails to run)

Tags: c#, dotnet-cli, .net-7.0

Version: dotnet-sdk: 7.0.100-rc.2.22477.23 from snap.
Basically it builds fine, but fails to run on linux.

What config should I set to run it?

target=net7.0, unpublished: (e.g. bin/Debug/net7.0/helloworld)

> seg fault on load.

target=net7.0, published by: `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -f net7.0`

> seg fault on load.

target=net6.0, unpublished:

> Error: "You must install .NET to run this application."

target=net6.0, published by: `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -f net6.0`

> OK

target=windows, net6.0/7.0, unpublished by: `dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -f net6.0` (or 7.0)

> OK (on windows)

PS:
***dotnet sdk 6.0 is out of question because it is is broken out-of-box***: does not work with vscode; dotnet cli broken.

The program is a minimal helloworld.

```
using System;
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net462;net6.0;net7.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

(.net framework is OK on Mono and windows)

Comment: "dotnet sdk 6.0 is out of question because it is is broken out-of-box: does not work with vscode; dotnet cli broken." - on what platform, precisely? I've used it on multiple flavours of Linux, Windows, and Mac... if that's not working for you, and .NET 7 is only partially working for you, that may suggest that something is broken on your system rather than the fault being in dotnet.

Comment: maybe you are seeing this that I found back a few years?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57715978/3225

Comment: What is `dotnet push`? (Do you mean `dotnet publish`?) Also what is the Linux distribution you are using? Keep in mind not all Linux distributions are officially supported, https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/7.0/supported-os.md#linux

Comment: @LexLi I fixed the typo. I am on Ubuntu 20.04, which is listed as supported (and snap dotnet is listed as official support). Also given that published net6.0 program can run, it is more likely to be a config/environmental problem than a hard compatibility defect.

Comment: .net 7 is still in RC and won't be released until November.  Even when it is, it will be under short term support since the even numbered version are long term support.  .net 6 should work fine on your platform and certainly works with vs code.  It will be supported until at least november 2024.

Comment: .NET 6 *definitely* works on Ubuntu 20.04. If you're having problems with that, I'd focus on diagnosing that problem rather than moving on to .NET 7.0.

Comment: I believe Microsoft is more than happy to hear more from you if you open a bug report with the details, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues

Comment: You need to download the runtime version of core that is same as on the build machine : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng Thanks. I just realized that dotnet publish seems to download binaries, and thus published self containing program is irrelevant to local runtime. (I thought it was copied from local install)

Comment: The publish setup.exe updates the windows dll allowing app to run on deployed machine just like commercial software.  I didn't realize the is must download the runtime version or Core as well.  Once you run the setup once all you have to do is to copy over the exe file from the build to the deploy machine since the windows stuff is already done.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. I found that it is solely snap dotnet packages issue. Binary release on dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

snap dotnet packages seems problematic.

```
$ snap list
core18             20220831                       2566   latest/stable    canonical**   base
core20             20220826                       1623   latest/stable    canonical**   base
dotnet-sdk         7.0.100-rc.2.22477.23          182    7.0/beta         dotnetcore**  classic
dotnet-runtime-60  6.0.10                         25     latest/stable    dotnetcore**  -
```

1. dotnet-runtime 6.0/7.0: missing symbol during dynamic linker.
   `$ DOTNET_ROOT=/snap/dotnet-runtime-60/25/ ./bin/Debug/net6.0/aaa`

> Failed to load /snap/dotnet-runtime-60/25/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.10/libcoreclr.so, error: /snap/dotnet-runtime-60/25/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.10/../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1:
> undefined symbol: __clock_nanosleep, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

2. dotnet-sdk 7.0rc2: if target=net7.0, output program crash during dynamic linker.
   `$ ./bin/Debug/net7.0/aaa`

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Both two issues specific to snap packages, not on packages from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Side note on runtime trouble shooting:

- dotnet publish download binaries, thus irrelavant to local runtime.
  Probably using: `~/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.*`
- Trouble shooting runtime searching, in addition to strace:

  > export COREHOST_TRACE=1
  > export COREHOST_TRACEFILE=host.txt